using THTTPSoapDispatcher and THTTPSoapPascalInvoker for https in Delphi
By Delphi I developed a stand alone webserver for http. I used THTTPSoapDispatcher and THTTPSoapPascalInvoker in it.
How can I use them for https? Do THTTPSoapDispatcher and THTTPSoapPascalInvoker  work for https too? How?

I would consider using a reverse proxy which provides HTTPS (Apache or nginx).
